# how to use javascript interface in android and how to display the result in android dialog box

Tags: javascript, android, html

***please explain me clearly as i am new to javascript and android****

how to create additon and subtraction operation of two random numbers  in java script (using javascript interface)  and on clicking addition and subtraction button (button logic must be written in android) result it must be dispalyed in android alert or dialog box

*//using javascript interface in main activity//*
//*using android button we need to disply result in android dialog box//*

***please explain me clearly as i am new to javascript and android****

Comment: This feels like homework. What is the purpose of operating on random numbers? Did you intentionally use the word random, or are you expecting those numbers to come from computations, or user input? Your question needs more details.

Comment: Sorry for improper Question..I ment to say that i need to declare additon and subtraction function in html file using java script..then this logic must be linked to two android buttons(add and sub)...i must enter two numbers and if i click on the add button the result of those two numbers must be displayed in android alert box...please help me

Comment: please explain me clearly sir..i am new to android and java script.

Answer (score 0):

1)First, write a class in android, this class will call by javascript :

```
public class JavaScriptCallFunc {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptCallFunc(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void showToastMsg(String s) {
        //do something

        Toast.makeText(mContext, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

2)addJavascriptInterface for webview in activity

```
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptCallFunc(this), "Android");
```

3)call java function in javascript

```
function callAndroidShowToast(msg) {
    Android.showToastMsg(msg);
```

}

Comment: down vote favorite
 

please explain me clearly as i am new to javascript and android*

how to create additon and subtraction operation of two random numbers in java script (using javascript interface) and on clicking addition and subtraction button (button logic must be written in android) result it must be dispalyed in android alert or dialog box

//using javascript interface in main activity// //using android button we need to disply result in android dialog box//

please explain me clearly as i am new to javascript and android*